# searching Exchange mailbox by email address using SearchFilterCollection

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, searchfiltercollection

I am searching an email inbox (on Exchange 2010) using Exchange Web Services.

In my SearchFilterCollection I would like to include the `From.Address` property of the Email message, as I only want to retrieve emails that include a certain domain (such as @domain.co.uk)

here is my code:

```
SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.HasAttachments, true));

// **** PROBLEM HERE ON BELOW LINE****       
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.From, "@domain.co.uk")); // 

// add the exceptions
for (int iEx = 0; iEx < e2c.emailExceptions.Count; iEx++)
    {
    searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.Not(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, e2c.emailExceptions[iEx])));
    }

    ItemView view = new ItemView(100);
    view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);

    // Find the first email message in the Inbox that has attachments. This results in a FindItem operation call to EWS.
    FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilterCollection, view);
```

is there a good way to include the email address in the SearchFilter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created a search folder the other day that did the same thing, using the example from the [How to: Work with search folders by using EWS in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn592094%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) topic:

```
// Create a search filter to express the criteria
// for the folder.
EmailAddress manager = new EmailAddress("sadie@contoso.com");

SearchFilter.IsEqualTo fromManagerFilter =
    new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.Sender, manager);
```

Now this is using the Sender property, not the From property. I think you could simply replace one for the other, but I didn't test to be sure.

Comment: do you think its possible to do something like: 

`SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring fromManagerFilter =                new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Sender, "@bankofcyprus.co.uk");` ?

Comment: I would think that would work, but I just tried and got no results when I thought I should have gotten results. But I didn't get an error. I can look at my code a little more this weekend - can't right now.

Comment: So I didn't get results using the ContainsSubstring search filter when I would have expected to. I did however get the results I expected when I used the following ASQ search: 

    `string queryString = "from:\"domain.co.uk\"";`
    `FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems (WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, queryString, view);`

Comment: thanks Mimi, so it looks like the only option is replace my EWS SearchFilter collection with a dynamically created AQS query string...

Comment: any thoughts on this issue: [EWS retrieve mail item attachment error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059919/exchange-web-services-convert-emailitem-attachment-from-base64-string-to-byte)